# SQL Server with Order by and select top 1 very slow

Tags: sql-server

This query without the TOP 1 works in a second with the top 1, it takes 8 seconds. Any ideas how I can improve this ?

```
SELECT top 1  bw.id as workflow_id,bw.status_id workflow_status_id, bo. record_id,bo.addr_line_1, bw.created_by 
from dbo.input_Oct bo  left outer join dbo.onebyone_workflow bw on bw.record_id = bo.record_id and (job_id = 18) 
where (bw.id IS NULL)
order by bo.match_result asc ,bo.unique_address desc, bo.record_id asc
```

Comment: Do you want `TOP 1`?

Comment: well this would return a few thousand and I just need top 1 yeah

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH Resultaat AS (select bw.id, ....
                   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by 
                      bw.id ASC
                   ) AS RM 
                   from ....
) select * from Resultaat  where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer Joins are expensive. I'd try moving the AND from the Left Outer Join and putting it in the where. I'm not sure which table it is in, so you might need to change the same slightly.

```
SELECT top 1 bw.id as workflow_id, bw.status_id workflow_status_id,
             bo. record_id,bo.addr_line_1, bw.created_by 
FROM dbo.input_Oct bo  
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.onebyone_workflow bw on bw.record_id = bo.record_id and 
WHERE bw.id IS NULL AND job_id = 18
ORDER BY bo.match_result asc, bo.unique_address desc, bo.record_id asc
```

Comment: problem is there is a reason why that "and" is on that level since I can have multiple similar "record_id" in onebyone_workflow table and need the job_id to pick correct one

Comment: This would still work if it was moved to the where clause.
Have you turned on the Execution plans in SQL Server management Studio, you will see where the delay is. This is an icon near the Execute button.

Comment: Tried adding it to the where clause and it makes the query run instant but the results are wrong then. It needs to be on the outer join level. I ran the execution plan thing its divided 33% over 3 indexes.

Comment: So the problem is in the LEFT OUTER JOIN Clause.
I'm sure that you can amend the WHERE clause to return the correct data. Can you post the table schema's, cut down so only the required fields are shown?